# convert a date into a timestamp

Tags: php

Okay so basically I have two variables one called `$day` and another called `$time` what I'm trying to do is convert both of these into a unix time-stamp so for example;

```
$day = 'Monday';
$time = '14:00:00';
```

So what I'm looking for is a `$timestamp` variable that would echo out the next `Monday` coming up at `14:00:00` in a unix timestamp format.

I'm guessing the hardest part of this would be the fact that the day is not a specific date more a day of the week meaning it would have to select the next `monday` coming up, or the next `tuesday...` for example.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: get the current date, seek forward to the next monday, add your time and get the unix-timestamp. now go implement that code - if you get any problems, the PHP-documentation for the datetime-functions is very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor for the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class is pretty good at figuring this sort of thing out:

```
<?php
$day = 'Monday';
$time = '14:00:00';

$date = new DateTime("next $day $time");
echo $date->getTimestamp();
// 1475503200
```

Comment: Thankyou; really appreciate that alot. Solved my original question will mark as answer shortly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
echo $datetime->format('U');
```

**Solution One:**

[mktime](http://ie.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) - Get Unix timestamp for a date

```
echo mktime(23, 24, 0, 11, 3, 2009);
1257290640
```

Returns the Unix timestamp corresponding to the arguments given. This timestamp is a long integer containing the number of seconds between the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT) and the time specified.

Arguments may be left out in order from right to left; any arguments thus omitted will be set to the current value according to the local date and time.

```
mktime($isAM ? $hrs : ($hrs + 12), $mins, $secs, $m, $d, $y);
```

To handle AM/PM just add 12 to hours if PM.

**Solution Two:**

`strtotime` Returns a timestamp on success, FALSE otherwise.

```
echo strtotime('2012-07-25 14:35:08' );
```

**Output:**

```
1343219708
```